# I want to use AWS Cognito with existed website. How can I link each other?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I already have a heavy user table in an existed website and server doesn't host in AWS.
I wanna use AWS Cognito for a mobile app of this site. So, need to check my server first when login/sign in. 
But many blogs and examples look like only for serverless service.
I saw [Accessing Server-side Resources after Sign-in](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/scenario-backend.html). But this access server after getting token. 
I saw [Adding a User Pool Lambda Trigger](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html). But not sure this can fit with my case. 
I know I need to test these things first. 
But just I wanna get some advice in here first. 
So, Please give me advice. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can do one thing, you can use cognito in application using aws-sdk which will do signin/singup

add trigger of cognito add save data to dynamo DB table or you can send data your database also.

another case if like you can add trigger, it  will check for in both cognito and login your table to having user info and then allow the sign in.

OR

You can import your user data to cognito.